# Unable to mock the void method of Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, mockito, powermock

I've below void method which I am looking to get mock of.

```
public void updateEmployee(EmployeeDto dto) {
    Employee d = convertToEntity(dto);
    employeeRepository.updateEmployee(d.getEmployeeName(), d.getEmployeeDescription(),
            d.getEmployeeOwnerEmployeeId(), d.getEmployeeCode(), d.getStatus());
}
```

But I am getting below error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
    at com.xxx.EmployeeServiceTest.test_UpdateEmployee(EmployeeServiceTest.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Test method

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StatusEnum.class})
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Employee employeeMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepositoryMock;

    @Mock
    private EmployeeDto employeeDtoMock;

    @Mock
    private StatusEnum statusEnum;

    @Mock
    private Exception ex;

    List<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // To mock static methods or class
        mockStatic(StatusEnum.class);       
    }


    @Test
    public void test_UpdateEmployee() {
        doNothing().when(employeeServiceImpl).saveEmployee(any(EmployeeDto.class));
        employeeServiceImpl.updateEmployee(employeeDtoMock);

        /*doAnswer((i) -> {
            System.out.println("Employee setName Argument = " + i.getArgument(0));
            assertTrue("Pankaj".equals(i.getArgument(0)));
            return null;
        }).when(employeeServiceImpl).updateEmployee(employeeDtoMock);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create `employeeServiceImpl` ? Also, you show code for `updateEmployee` & tests for `saveEmployee`

Comment: @SabirKhan - I've added `employeeServiceImpl` , `updateEmployee` code has been shown already.

Comment: @PAA Which runner are you using?

Comment: @MadhuBhat - I am using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StatusEnum.class})`

Comment: @PAA if you are unit testing `updateEmployee` method of `EmployeeServiceImpl` class, then why do you need to have `doNothing().when(employeeServiceImpl).saveEmployee(any(EmployeeDto.class))`?

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to test here? `EmployeeServiceImpl` is not a Mock but the thing you are injecting mocks into. You cannot obviously therefore do this: `doNothing().when(employeeServiceImpl)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception here seem clear to me, `employeeServiceImpl` seems not to be a mock.
How did you instantiate it ? Using `Mockito.mock` or `@Mock` on the field ?

--- Edit

To clarify my answer, in the `@Before` (or equivalent in your test class) instantiate your service with mockito :

```
this.employeeService = Mockito.mock(EmployeeService.class);
```

or

```
@Mock
private EmployeeService employeeService;
```

And then it should work.

--- Edit
So seeing how you inject your mock I think I might get what's happening.
In fact `@InjectMocks` does not make your `EmployeeService a mock`. It allows mockito to know let your framework create the bean and injects the mocks you have created in it.

Here if you have declared your repository as a mock like this

```
@Mock
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
```

Then a mock of type `EmployeeRepository` will be injected inside the `employeeService` instance, which is not a mock.

Then if it is in fact the repository you want to mock, you should put it in the `when` in your tests like :

```
    doNothing().when(employeeRepository).saveEmployee(any(EmployeeDto.class));
employeeServiceImpl.saveEmployee(employeeDtoMock);
```

Then calling your service will go into your service `saveEmployee` function, but when it would reach the repository which is a mock it would work as expected.

If it is in fact the whole service you want to mock then instantiate it using `@Mock` instead of `@InjectMocks`.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Indeed you are right. I modified my answer to explain my thoughts

Comment: @PAA you're using `@InjectMocks`, which does not declare `EmployeeService` as a mock but rather Inject mocks into it. I'll eplain it in my answer so I have more space to write it down !

Comment: @PAA your welcome! Glad I could help! Do not hesitate to mark your question as resolved :)

Comment: @PAA So what do you want to test here ? You want to test that when you call `updateEmployee` it calls a repository ?

Comment: @ALeDref - I pre-assume every test method should have asserts statement and looking to do that with void method. Yes, although its mock, but still call repository

Comment: @PAA Ok thanks I wasn't sure I got your question. In fact here if what you want to test is whether the repository is called, you can use the `verify` from mockito. For your `updateEmployee` method for assertion at the end of the test: `verify(employeeRepository).updateEmployee(anyString(), anyString(),
            anyString(), anyString(), anyString());` Assuming that all of the parameters are strings of course. You can also check the values of these parameters, see official doc [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4) if you want more detail